# MOGENERATOR core data classes throwing protocol error

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mogenerator

I wrote a script to regenerate classes with MOGENERATOR, and it correctly generates them, but it throws an error now in all the non-underscsore classes, why? The files are shown in the following gooogle doc, and they're in the right directories, so I'm confused. Google docs link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tJGB4BXWJB8lY2kkZTKwDT1FICLeP_P5QZtJM_iVySs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your `mogenerator` command? And have you edited those files after running `mogenerator`?

Comment: Command: MODEL_PATH="/Users/Kson/Documents/Github/ten.xcdatamodeld"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="/Users/odels/ModelMachine"
mogenerator --v2 --model $MODEL_PATH --output-dir $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Comment: I changed the pathnames for privacy, but that's the command, and no I havent changed the xcode project after running the mogen

Comment: all i did was modify one core data attribute and then run the mogen script above

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: its printed on the google doc image

Comment: duplicate interface definition for class...